# MongoDB - Wampserver : Class 'Mongo' not found

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to install MongoDb on windows platform. I'm using PHP with WampServer.

But while executing the PHP program it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 19

So is there any way to check whether MongoDB is running with PHP or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error - 'Mongo' class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927255/fatal-error-mongo-class-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check php loaded extensions using phpinfo() function whether mongoDB extension is loaded or not.

Do check these as well.

[Fatal Error - 'Mongo' class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927255/fatal-error-mongo-class-not-found)

[Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724532/fatal-error-class-mongo-not-found-in-xampp)

Add the following line to your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

Docs Link: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: Resolved !!!! I checked with Wamp apache setting made changes. now its able to access Mongo code.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this possible solution**

Copy `c:\wamp\bin\php\php-5.3.x\ext\`

Edit `c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.xx\bin\php.ini` and add the line where the extensions are loaded.

**Why run WAMP on 32bit Windows 7 64bit?**

The Mongo PHP driver does not have a 64bit binary win32, if you are running the 64bit version of WAMP, PHP will refuse to load the 32-bit version of php_mongo.dll.