# MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

When executing the following PHP code:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in (...)

MongoDB extension seems properly installed (I copied `php_mongodb.dll` to ext folder and updated `php.ini`).

PHP seems to confirm that the extension is running properly as the following code confirms it is loaded:

```
echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

Also, `phpinfo()` shows that mongodb extension has been loaded.

---

**UPDATE**: my problem is still not solved.

`phpinfo()` clearly shows that the driver is loaded:

[image]

But I am still receiving the same fatal error.

Comment: MongoDB != MongoClient

Comment: http://php.net/MongoDB http://php.net/MongoClient

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this! How can I install the MongoDB library for PHP on WIndows (official instructions are for Linux only)?

Comment: In addition, official instructions mae use of "pecl" command which I don't have...

Comment: You installed MongoDB, according to your question. You only need to use the correct class now. ;)

Comment: `Application developers should consider using this extension in conjunction with the » MongoDB PHP library, which implements the same higher level APIs found in MongoDB drivers for other languages.` http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: Thanks! and that's exactly what I'm trying to do but can't figure out how to install the MongoDB PHP lib (since I seem to have installed the basic driver only)

Comment: Warning: This extension that defines this class is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used. Alternatives to this class include:
MongoDB\Driver\Manager - http://php.net/MongoClient. Why don't you just use `$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");`, as the documentation is highly suggesting you to do ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The class `MongoClient` is part of the legacy PECL package [mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) but not anymore of the up-to-date [mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) package.

And since you have the `mongodb` extension installed, and not the `mongo` one, this is why you are getting the error

> ```
> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found
> ```

On MongoDB PHP driver github repo, the release note about the version 1.0.0, is suggesting developers to use `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` instead of `MongoClient`

> **Changes from our legacy mongo extension**
>
> Most significantly, the legacy driver's MongoClient, MongoDB, and
> MongoCollection classes have been obsoleted by the
> MongoDB\Driver\Manager class, which is the new gateway for connecting
> and executing queries, commands, and write operations.

<sup>*Source:: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.0.0*</sup>

So, here is [the replacement class documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) and the snippet of code that should replace yours :

```php
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

---

As the documentation is prompting it, the class is deprecated.

> **Warning** This extension that defines this class is deprecated. Instead,
> the [MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) extension should be used. Alternatives to this class
> include:
>
> - [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php)

<sup>*Source: http://php.net/MongoClient*</sup>

---

From what I read [on their github repository release history](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.0.0), the class you are trying to use has been obsoleted since the version of `mongodb 1.0.0`, so, on the version `1.6.0` you are, this class is not even part of the `dll` anymore.

That is confirmed by [this issue on their github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/300)

> derickr commented on Apr 16
>
> MongoClient is a class from the old legacy
> driver and is not supposed to be available in this one. The new driver
> has \MongoDB\Driver\Manager, and, the accompanying library has
> \MongoDB\Client.
>
> You either need to install the old legacy extension (pecl install
> mongo) and use PHP 5.x, or update your code to use this new driver's
> classes as the old driver is not available for PHP 7. There is an
> upgrade guide at
> http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/upgrade-guide/

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/300#issuecomment-210820288*</sup>

---

Another way, as suggested by the MongoDB member quoted here above is to use this pecl extension: https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo instead of https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb but please also notice the warning there stating:

> This package has been superseded, but is still maintained for bugs and security fixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are lots of pages said to be "deprecated" and refers to another page which also deprecated.. Examples in the PHP manual shows "$m = new MongoClient()" which  doesn't work anymore, I also tried my chance with "$m = new MongoDB()" which also doesn't work too.
So this solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB(mongo-php-library) and MongoClient(ext-mongo) are different extensions. MongoClient extension is deprecated. If you want to use MongoClient(ext-mongo) related classes, use a wrapper like this one;

https://github.com/mitsh/mongo-php-adapter

Adapter to provide ext-mongo interface on top of mongo-php-library

You don't need to change anything on your project. Just install and include it with composer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30275564)