# PHP: Class 'MongoClient' not found after installed (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, apache

I have mongo server install and the mondo php extension enable:

[image]

Why am I still getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ...

My code:

```
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient();
var_dump($m);
```

How I install mongo server:

```
`$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-server`
```

How I install mongo client:

```
`$ sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev`
`$ sudo pecl install mongodb`
```

Add `extension=mongodb.so` at the end of php.ini

Restart Apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

What have I missed?

Comment: Did you do sudo pecl install mongodb or sudo pecl install mongo?

Comment: i think i might have done it with `mongo`

Comment: but when i tried to install mongodb - `pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.7`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/php-mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your Ubuntu Software Centre and search for `mongo driver`.
2. Select MongoDB Database Driver php5-mongo and install it.
3. Restart Apache: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

[image]

I have no idea what **mongodb** is installed for!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Run below command in your project using terminal:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Add below code in your php file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->db->collection;
```

Go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) documentation for more details.

Hope this may helpfull

Answer (score -1):

The [MongoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) class was provided with the now deprecated `mongo` driver. You installed the `mongodb` driver, which provides the [Manager](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) class:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var_dump($manager);
```

The `mongodb` driver provides [a minimal API for core driver functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php), but no classes such as `MongoClient`. The [MongoDB PHP library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) provides a high-level abstraction around this lower-level driver, e.g. a [Client](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Client.php) class, and can be installed with [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb).

Comment: yet i got result from that one `object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(25) "mongodb://localhost:27017" ["cluster"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port"]=> int(27017) ["type"]=> int(0) ["is_primary"]=> bool(false) ["is_secondary"]=> bool(false) ["is_arbiter"]=> bool(false) ["is_hidden"]=> bool(false) ["is_passive"]=> bool(false) ["tags"]=> array(0) { } ["last_is_master"]=> array(0) { } ["round_trip_time"]=> int(-1) } } }`

Comment: but still having the same problem with `$m = new MongoClient();`

Comment: `There is no class MongoClientwith the mongodbdriver;` then why do we have to install mongodb? Do u mean we have to install MongoClient via composer?

Comment: The `mongo` extension, which provided `MongoClient` and other classes is deprecated; you cannot use these classes with `mongodb` driver. The replacement extension `mongodb` provides a low-level API *only*; libraries like `MongoDB PHP library` are built on top of the new `mongodb` driver and provide a convenient high level API. You can choose to build your logic using the basic low-level API coming with the `mongodb` driver you installed, or make your day easier with the help of e.g. `MongoDB PHP library`, which you can install with Composer.