# Class 'MongoDB' not found in fatfree (f3)

Tags: php, mongodb, fat-free-framework

Iv recently been trying to upload my php application from xampp which i have installed on my home machine to a server. Now the code works perfectly on xampp at home and the mongodb driver works as expected, however after migrating it to the LAMP server, the f3 framework throws this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB' not found in /nfs/fs0/home/dhu/www/fatfree/lib/db/mongo.php on line 107
Internal Server Error

Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB' not found
```

In reference i looked up the line it is complaining about and its this one :

```
$this->db=new \MongoDB(new $class($dsn,$options?:array()),$dbname);
```

And after looking up solutions on stack and other websites they said to check the version of mongo etc installed so i look it up on the php side to see what was enabled and it returns :

### PHP INFO ()

```
PHP Version 5.6.24-0+deb8u1
mongodb
mongodb support enabled
mongodb version 1.1.8
mongodb stability   stable
libmongoc version   1.3.5
libbson version 1.3.5
```

So since mongo is both installed and enabled on the php server im unsure what exactly the issue is with line 107 in the fatfree framework, does anyone have any idea's? Any help would be appreciated.

---

So after no real solutions been found here im gonna update to see if i can get more help.

### Update

Note the server settings can be found here:

http://lamp0.cs.stir.ac.uk/

and the error here:

http://lamp0.cs.stir.ac.uk/~dhu/

The line its referring too is:

```
$this->db=new \MongoDB(new $class($dsn,$options?:array()),$dbname);
```

Within the MONGODB library, mongo.php. After looking at various ways to set the DB up and trying to rewrite the setup code nothing seems to work....

### Update 2

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://mydetails:27017");
```

If i removed the fatfree framework this line does not throw an error during setup which is surprising as i expected it to be unable to find MongoDB\Driver however it had no problem, its main problem seems simply to be that one line in the fatfree framework and im unsure why...

Comment: The mongodb php extension is likely also a dependency- see http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php

Comment: Is that seperate from what i listed above from the PHP_info page? The problem is i have not setup the server on the other machine so i assumed the mongo php extension had been installed however all i can check is the mongodb section of PHP Info which had the values i listed above...

Comment: You're right, the phpinfo you listed should indicate the extension is installed. Could still be related to the extension version though, this answer could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/php-mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found

Comment: You are probably at PHP 7 which ditched the old MongoDB extension. F3 doesn't support the new MongoDB class of the latest PHP version yet.

Comment: hmm on the php info section it states the version is : PHP Version 5.6.24-0+deb8u1, i was hoping you were right as that may have been easy to solve by upgrading php...

Comment: @Dean219 did you restart the server after installing the mongo driver ?

Comment: I have no control over the server so im unsure about whether it had been restarted or not, could it be a reason the driver would not load correctly?

Comment: I had once similar problem with mongo.. it was something about having old libs php in composer cache..  probably not related in your case.. but try clearing composer cache.

Comment: Try `var_dump($manager);` and let us know the response. Also check mongodb logs if it can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add MongoDB as dependency in the `composer.json` file of your Fat-Free Framework.

Just add MongoDB to the require dependency list, if it is not there create one like below.

```
"require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0"
},
```

Then run `composer install` again. Now you can reference MongoDB classes inside your code.

Comment: Im still testing out a number of solutions posted here and reinstalling versiona of the software on the server so once i get back to this stage if there is an error and this solves it i will let you know, but i did check and you were right that there was no requirement in composer.json, so it looks promising, i will keep you updated and thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 2):

First install autoload class for mongodb in your project.Then try with below code
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");