# MongoDB\Driver\Manager or MongoClient not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I tried this code below, but not working - No Output Showing

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var_dump($manager);
?>
```

Also tried another code shown below, but this also produces no output

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

> ```
> $ mongod --version
> db version v3.4.4
> git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
> OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
> allocator: tcmalloc
> modules: none
> build environment:
> distmod: ubuntu1404
>     distarch: x86_64
>     target_arch: x86_64
> ```
>
> **
>
> ```
> $ php --version
> PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
> ```

**

> ```
> $ php -i | grep extension_dir
> extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20131226 => /usr/lib/php/20131226
> $ cd /usr/lib/php/20131226
> $ ls
> calendar.so  exif.so      gettext.so  mbstring.so  pdo.so    readline.so   sockets.so  sysvshm.so    xmlreader.so  xsl.so
> ctype.so     fileinfo.so  iconv.so    mongodb.so   phar.so   shmop.so      sysvmsg.so  tokenizer.so  xml.so
> dom.so       ftp.so       json.so     opcache.so   posix.so  simplexml.so  sysvsem.so  wddx.so       xmlwriter.so
> ```
>
> **

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

produces output - not loaded
```

**php.ini**

[image]

Comment: check mongodb driver with phpinfo() and confirm.

Comment: @AbhayPS plz check the attached image - phpinfo(). Is it Ok?

Comment: looks good. can you also look into apache error log? That would show the actual error.

Comment: @AbhayPS error log says - PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 3

Comment: I think you need to use "new MongoDB\Client()" instead of "new MongoClient()"

Comment: @AbhayPS - Issue Solved ----                                                          $manager= new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
These links also helpes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532297/7291000   ------------             
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37322259/7291000

Comment: @AbhayPS Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Glad that you could solve it. They changed pretty much everything.

Comment: Hi, its a bit late but if any one like to read a php mongodb tutorial. you can find here. https://programmerblog.net/php-mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

First one need to have mongodb installed and a link to it in php script **'vendor/autoload.php'**. In many cases you need to check your hosting:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then if you use MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of MongoDB driver, you code will look like the following tested examples of CRUD operations:

***Create** a document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc = ['name' => 'John', age => 33, profession => 'Guess what?'];
$bulkWrite->insert($doc);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by name with a limit:

```
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by MongoDb _id with a limit:

```
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Update** document in the collection*:  (Read more about options upsert and multi [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php))

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'Guess what?']];
$options = ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false];
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Delete** document in the collection - Delete*:

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter= ['name' => 'John', age => 35];
$options = ['limit' => 1];
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```