# PHP MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, classnotfound

Hi I have been trying to connect to mongodb from php. I am using the below dll:

> php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

I was going through one of the threads on stackoverflow [PHP MongoDB: Fatal Error: Class 'Mongo CLient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/php-mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found) ,which mentions that MongoClient() class has been deprecated. Instead of it now we need to use something like this:

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
```

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
$db = $m->testdb;
echo "Connected to db";
?>
```

Still I am getting error for class not found. Does anyone have any idea about it? Or do I have to import something? Please help.

Comment: I have placed the dll in C:/wamp/php/php5.5.12/ext/ and mentioned the name of the extension as well in php.ini file with the following statement :

extension=php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

I have also restarted the wamp server. I do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: @endo64 any idea on this

Comment: @b.enoit.be please help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that \ is missing at the time of object creation.

```
 $m = new \MongoClient();
```

or

```
$m = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

The error you are getting might be due to the namespace issue. Try both the solutions one by one and see if it helps.