# Why Mongodb get me error when i call it with MongoClient?

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I install mongodb on xampp . It show successfully installed in phpinfo. But when I call it says me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ...

my code :

```
echo extension_loaded('mongodb');
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

I install it manually. First line echo true.

Comment: When i use new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://example.com:27017") it dosnt return error but i cant work with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

`MongoClient` seems to be part of [mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) extension. You are checking for [mongodb](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php) extension which wouldn't define it.

Comment: Hi. when i use extension_loaded('mongo'); it dos not return anything. How can i define it?

Comment: You need to load the extension I would imagine.